# Xpages - Repeat control / view SSJS

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have the exact same design of a database on live and DEV, however, when I have a repeat control on a page, it works as expected on DEV, pulling in the status of documents from a view but not on live, where it just lists the number of the document in the view. It also doesn't seem to return any unique values. I'm using a dbcolumn to get the values, and tried wrapping an @unique around it, and then using a script lib to handle the unique entries, but no such luck.  Image attached and code below. Any ideas?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>%</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
            <tbody>

                <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="row">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript://var result = @DbColumn("", "vwStatusStats", 1);
//var result = session.evaluate("@DbColumn(\"\"; ; \"vwStatusStats\"; 1)").elementAt(0) 


//result = session.evaluate("@Unique");

//return result
//return @Unique(@DbColumn("", "vwStatusStats", 1))

return DbColumnArray("", "", "", "unique", "", "vwStatusStats", 1)
}]]></xp:this.value>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xp:text escape="true"
                                id="computedField11">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:row}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:text>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xp:text escape="true"
                                id="computedField1">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var v:NotesView = database.getView("vwStatusStats");
var vec:NotesViewEntryCollection = v.getAllEntriesByKey(row);
return vec.getCount().toString()}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:text>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <xp:text escape="true"
                                id="computedField2">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var total = getComponent("cmpTotal").getValue();
var amount = getComponent("computedField1").getValue();

var result = (amount / total) * 100;

return result}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:text>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xp:repeat>

                <tr>
                    <td>Total</td>                      
                    <td>
                        <xp:text escape="true" id="cmpTotal">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var v:NotesView = database.getView("vwStatusStats");

return v.getEntryCount().toString()}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:text></td>
                        <td>
                            <xp:text escape="true"
                                id="computedField3">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var total = getComponent("cmpTotal").getValue();
var amount = getComponent("cmpTotal").getValue();

var result = (amount / total) * 100;

return result}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:text></td>
                </tr>               

            </tbody>
                    </table>
```

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 0):

Check for multiple views with the same name / alias in the live database. Your live version could be looking to a different view than the one you expect.

Best practice is also to ensure an `@DbColumn` call passes `@DbName()` as the first parameter. It's still going to have to do the same amount of work, but it's going to ensure consistent results ("" won't work for XPiNC). Using SSJS / Java to get the View and return `getColumnValues()` is also likely to be better performing that `@DbColumn()`, from analysis by Howard Greenberg. As an extra bonus, it might be worth looking at this XSnippet for use of Repeat Control facets for the HTML that wraps your repeat https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=repeat-with-header-and-footer-facets. It ensure the HTML for the table doesn't get additional HTML injected.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been out of the office... No other view name or aliases exist with said view name.... I have also changed to @DbName() as suggested with no change, and have deleted and re-copied the view from DEV, where it works. Viewing the view in the notes clients shows values as expected also

Answer (score 0):

It seems your live view is corrupted. Open it with Notes client to verify it does contain expected values.
One possibility can be corruption of "programmatic name" value in column properties. Sometimes, especially by copy/paste in view design your columns get the same dollar value ($1 for example) for columns with different formula. That causes "strange" values in one of those columns, completely different from its formula. Remove programmatic value, new one will be generated automatically.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been out of the office. The programmatic names were the same, that was the first thing I checked. Re-entering the name doesn't fix the problem either. I should note, there is literally only 1 column in this view....

Comment: Programmatic name is shared for all views, it may collide with column formula in other views.

Comment: I just gave the column a completely unique programmatic name, but still no joy. The column formula is literally just the field name too.

Comment: If I change the view formula to use a different field, for example, office location, everything works, but when I change it back to Status, it doesnt again.. Column / field content is string in both cases...

Comment: Double check isSummary flag in fields - both in documents and field table.

Comment: They are set to true, both the field that displays correctly, and the one which does not